# Ballerina 0.980.0 - How set timeout for jdbc:Client?

Tags: ballerina

I defined a jdbc:Client endpoint.

When I call an operation, if the DB is not available, the timeout error appears at 30000 ms.
How can I change the timeout time? Is this at the Hikari level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default client timeout is 30000ms. You can change this as follows.

```
endpoint jdbc:Client testDB {
    url: "...",
    username: "...",
    password: "...",
    poolOptions: { connectionTimeout: 1000 }
};
```

You can find more properties [here](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/sql.html#PoolOptions) in the API docs